Why is a Kernel Module not Loaded on an Pixel Phone running AOSP
What must I do for a kernel module to be loaded and effective on an Android phone?
I am compiling an AOSP for an old Pixel phone build and changed values in private/gs-google/drivers/thermal/exynos_cpu_cooling.c. I know that these get compiled into the module gs_thermal.ko. I then installed the compiled kernel and the modules with:
cd out/mixed/dist
adb root
adb remount
adb push *.ko vendor/lib/modules
adb reboot bootloader
<wait for phone to reboot into bootloader>
fastboot --cmdline androidboot.selinux=permissive flash:raw boot boot.img
fastboot flash dtbo dtbo.img
fastboot -w
fastboot reboot

After rebooting the phone, I do not see any effect of my changes. (I changed the ftrace logging output. A similar change had an effect in the aosp/... part of the Android kernel but not in private/gs-google/.... I believe my changes in aosp/ are not transmitted via a kernel module but compiled directly into the kernel.)
Strangely, I am not sure that my modified kernel module gets loaded. When I look at the vermagic of the kernel module in question, I do not see a -dirty postfix.
What steps can I take to understand whether a newly compiled kernel module is in fact running on a system? How could there even be a different kernel module running? Might I be totally off-track with my analysis? How could I further debug the issue?
